# ajax ,html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

how can I make the both messages (good and bad) replaced ?
let say if data in field is corrent display good and if not - display bad but than if I change it again so the message will change accordingly.

(Im new to all this)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#button').click(function(e){
            var result = true,
                ok = '<p>good</p>',
                failed = '<p>bad</p>',
                err;
            $('input').each(function(index,obj){
                var obj =   $(obj);
                if (obj.attr('id') == 'button'){
                    return false;
                }
                err =  validateInput(o);
                markInput(o,err);
                if (!err){
                    result = false;
                }
            });
            if (result){
                $('#myForm').after(good);
                $.ajax();
            }
            else{
                $('#myForm').after(bad);
                $.ajax();
            }

        });
```

Comment: Doing some research on that thing you're newly learning, before asking SO, is always a good idea. https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=tutorial%20jquery%20ajax

Comment: I tried but didnt understand... how can I make it disappear?

Comment: It seems like you might not be to the point of being ready to have a well formed question. I'd walk through an ajax tutorial or two (http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ would be a good start) and work from there.

Comment: if you didn't understand it, it might be wise to take a step back and first learn to understand the code you copied?

Comment: @BostonJohn Please do not link to `w3schools`. They are not affiliated with the w3c, and often have incorrect information.

Comment: Your title does not say much. Please make it more specific for better results. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.after` have an element that acts as a placeholder for the message and update its html:

```
<form>
    <!-- all your code -->
    <p id="message"></p>
</form>

// JavaScript
$("#myForm #message").html(good);
// also just `$("#message")` will work, and you can probably leave
// the `<p>` parts off of `good` and `bad`
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 if (result){
                $('#myForm').after(good);
                $.ajax();
            }
            else{
                $('#myForm').after(bad);
                $.ajax();
            }
```

To:

```
 if (result){
                $('#myForm').after(ok);
                $.ajax();
            }
            else{
                $('#myForm').after(failed);
                $.ajax();
            }
```

You didn't use the vars you created, named "ok" and "failed", instead you put "good" and "bad" in your .after() which don't exist. Also consider using $('#messagePlaceHolder').replace(ok or fail) instead of .after where messagePlaceHolder is a .

Comment: sorry I did already change it but now the problem is when failed appear even if I correct everything ok still not show